# Entity Framework deleting linked table

Tags: c#, entity-framework

If I have the following setup

```
public class Device
{
    public virtual ICollection<Folder> PresentInFolders { get; set; }
    public virtual RoutingRule RoutingRule { get; set; }
}

public class Folder
{
    public virtual ICollection<Device> Devices { get; set; }
}
```

Is the following code enough to disassociate and delete all linking rows?

```
foreach (var folder in device.PresentInFolders.ToList())
{
   folder.Devices.Remove(device);
}
device.PresentInFolders.Clear();
```

Answer (score 1):

As i can see you have setup a many to many relation between Device and Folder. It should not be necessary to delete from the two ends of the relation so this should do the job:

```
folder.Devices.Clear();
```

Comment: And make sure that `folder.Devices` is loaded, otherwise EF will not notice the change.